# Sorting polynomial terms based on degrees

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, polynomial-math

I have this code which is about polynomials multiplication.
I meet no error, just what I want is to sort the terms based on degrees (from lower degree to higher). 
 If I add condition in operator* in //commented part, it will be printed too many of times. I would like to know if I can use m_Polynomial.sort()? If yes how? If not, what other methods can I use?

As it is both for printing polynomials and their multiplication result it would be nice if it could be added in print function.

Also if it is possible to change the printing style of Polynomials to desired format (to add coefficients of same degree terms)

**Minimal code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


typedef struct Node
{
    double  cof;      // coefficient 
    int     deg;      // degree
} Node;

class CPolynomial
{
public:
    CPolynomial();
    CPolynomial(const string& file);
    ~CPolynomial();
    CPolynomial operator*(const CPolynomial &right);
    CPolynomial& operator=(const CPolynomial &right);
    void Print() const;

private:
    void ReadFromFile(string file);

private:
    list<Node> m_Polynomial;
};



int main()
{
    CPolynomial p1("P3.txt");
    CPolynomial p2("P4.txt");
    CPolynomial p3;
    p1.Print();
    p2.Print();

    p3 = p1*p2;
    p3.Print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

CPolynomial::CPolynomial()
{
    Node term;
    term.cof = 0;
    term.deg = 0;
    m_Polynomial.push_back(term);
}

CPolynomial::~CPolynomial()
{
    m_Polynomial.clear();
}

CPolynomial::CPolynomial(const string& file)
{
    ReadFromFile(file);
}

CPolynomial CPolynomial:: operator*(const CPolynomial &right)
{
    CPolynomial result;
    result.m_Polynomial = m_Polynomial;

    for (list<Node>::iterator itr = result.m_Polynomial.begin(); itr != result.m_Polynomial.end(); ++itr)
    {
        itr->cof = 0;
        itr->deg = 0;
    }

    Node term;
    Node termR;
    Node temp;

    for (list<Node>::const_iterator it = m_Polynomial.begin(); it != m_Polynomial.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (list<Node>::const_iterator itR = right.m_Polynomial.begin(); itR != right.m_Polynomial.end(); ++itR)
        {
            term = *it;
            termR = *itR;

            temp.cof = termR.cof* term.cof;
            temp.deg = termR.deg + term.deg;

            for (list<Node>::iterator itr = result.m_Polynomial.begin(); itr != result.m_Polynomial.end(); ++itr)
            {
                if (temp.deg == itr->deg)
                {
                    temp.cof += itr->cof;
                    itr->cof = 0;
                }
            // if(temp.deg < it->deg)
            //result.m_Polynomial.insert(it, temp);
            }
            result.m_Polynomial.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

CPolynomial& CPolynomial:: operator=(const CPolynomial &right)
{

    this->m_Polynomial = right.m_Polynomial;
    return *this;
}

void CPolynomial::Print() const
{
    list<Node>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = m_Polynomial.begin(); it != m_Polynomial.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->cof == 0)
        {
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            if (it->cof > 0)
            {
                if (it != m_Polynomial.begin()) // if 'it' is not the first term, '+' is not necessary
                    cout << "+";
            }
            cout << it->cof;
            if (it->deg != 0)
                cout << "x^" << it->deg;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void CPolynomial::ReadFromFile(string file)
{
    Node term;
    fstream MyFile;
    string p;
    int num;

    MyFile.open(file);

    if (!MyFile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open input file" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        MyFile >> p >> num;

        std::list<Node>::iterator it = m_Polynomial.begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            MyFile >> term.deg >> term.cof;

            m_Polynomial.push_back(term);
        }
        MyFile.close();
    }

}
```

**P1.txt**

```
P 8
0 2
5 -3
12 5
2 6
5 7
3 -4
2 9
2 2
```

**P4.txt**

```
P 2
1 4
4 -3
```

Output

```
2-3^5+5x^12+6x^2+7x^5-4x^3+9x^2+2x^2         (P1)
4x^1-3x^4                                    (P2)
8x^1+20x^13-15x^16_12x^9-22x^4+12x^7+68x^3    (P1*P2)
```

desired output:

```
2+17x^2-4x^3+4x^5+5x^12
4x^1-3x^4 
8x^1+68x^3-22x^4+12x^7_12x^9+20x^13-15x^16
```

Comment: add a language tag

Comment: Why does your `operator*` operate on `*this`? That means if you say `a * b` then it modifies `a`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator modifies its left operand, why?

If you say `p3 = p1 * p2;` then it is wrong to modify `p1`, you should return a new object with a new value, and not alter the operands.

One solution is to provide `operator*=` as a member function that alters its left operand, then define `operator*` as a non-member function:

```
CPolynomial operator*(const CPolynomial& lhs, const CPolynomial& rhs)
{
  CPolynomial result = lhs;
  result *= rhs;
  return result;
}
```

The bug appears to be in `AddOneTerm` where you do the comparisons wrong. Your loop will insert the new term at the *first* position where `(term.deg >= it->deg)` but it should be the *last* position where that is true.

Also you should use `AddOneTerm(term)` instead  of `m_Polynomial.push_back(term)` in `ReadFromFile` to ensure the terms are kept in the correct order.

You also have very confusing use of iterators:

```
        std::list<Node>::iterator next_it;
        next_it = ++it;
```

Now both `next_it` and `it` have been incremented, so they are **both** the next term. Why?

I suggest something much simpler:

```
void CPolynomial::AddOneTerm(Node term)
{
    auto it = m_Polynomial.begin();
    while (it != m_Polynomial.end() && it->deg < term.deg)
    {
        ++it;
    }

    if (it != m_Polynomial.end() && term.deg == it->deg)
    {
        it->cof += term.cof;
    }
    else
    {
        m_Polynomial.insert(it, term);
    }
}
```

You could also define a comparison operator for `Node` objects:

```
bool operator<(const Node& l, const Node& r)
{
    return l.deg < r.deg;
}
```

Now you can easily sort your `list<Node>` structure, and you can use `lower_bound` to find the right position in `AddOneTerm`:

```
void CPolynomial::AddOneTerm(Node term)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(m_Polynomial.begin(), m_Polynomial.end(), term);

    if (it != m_Polynomial.end() && term.deg == it->deg)
    {
        it->cof += term.cof;
    }
    else
    {
        m_Polynomial.insert(it, term);
    }
}
```

Comment: all cof and degrees correct

Final result incorrect:
6x^1-9x^4

I am sorry how much I try I can't write in code format in comment

Comment: So don't put it in a comment, edit your question. You should also show all the relevant code, not just one function. Please read the docs for this site about how to ask questions, and how to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: Edited. Just the code is too long, I added relevant functions.
Consider they act properly for other funtions

Comment: _"Just the code is too long"_ That's why the site docs say to create a **minimal** complete verifiable example. Did you read them?

Comment: why no one helps me?:(

Comment: Your code is too long to skim easily, and it depends on separate input files (you could easily change it to hardcode that input, for the purposes of the question). If you expect people to spend their time helping you then you should spend your time making it easier. You also haven't said what you think the output should be. Your question is very poor. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and other answers at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Thanks for reply.

But for both methods suggested, there are some errors.
First: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
Second: namespace "std" has no member "lower_bound" 

Should I add some header file for using them? @Jonathan Wakely

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound tells you the header you need for `lower_bound`

Comment: the first one works perfectly, but second one results in error even with header:
Error 1 error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const' 

Anyway my problem is solved.Many many thanks @Jonathan Wakely

Comment: That error sounds like you didn't define the `bool operator<(const Node& l, const Node& r)` that I suggested. Using `lower_bound` means you need that.